# how to make repost button on website for mobile phones, which uses inside repost function

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

I need to realize current page link share button on website, i tried to do it using webshare api, but on all devices i got alert that browser version is out of date and i need to update it. Can you suggest any other ways?

```js
var shareButton = document.getElementById('share-button');
  shareButton.addEventListener('click', function () {

  if (navigator.share) {
    console.log("Your browser support")

      navigator.share({
        title: "title",
        text: "text",
        url: window.location.href,
      })
      .then(function () {
        console.log("Success")
      })
      .catch(function () {
        console.log("Error")
      })

    } else {
      alert("Your browser version is out of date")
    }
  })'''
```

```html
<div class="share-button-plugin mt-30">
                <button id="share-button"><i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i>Share</button>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

On Firefox website ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share ) is written that you should use `navigator.canShare()`

Also, there is a note:

> Secure context. This feature is available only in secure contexts (HTTPS), in some or all supporting browsers.

I would not use this feature in general, due to poor browser compatibility:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share#Browser_compatibility